# How to find changeset for specified block in wwf scenario

Tags: tfs, workflow-foundation

I have a wwf scenario somescenario.xaml in tfs. I want to find out, who, when and what for change some block in it. I need some function, like "annotate" for specified line in code. The problem is, that i can select some block but i cant annotate it in workflow designer. And if i open it in xaml editor, i can annotate specified line, but i cant select the block, which i need.

for example 
i want to know who make one of Sequence in scenario. But they all are the same, so i can identify it only in workflow designer

```
  <Sequence DisplayName="Предварительная настройка" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,51">
    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
      </scg:Dictionary>
  <Sequence DisplayName="Предварительная настройка" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,51">
    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
      </scg:Dictionary>
  <Sequence DisplayName="Предварительная настройка" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,51">
    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
      </scg:Dictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

View the XAML in the XML editor in Visusl Studio then use Annotate.

Comment: "if i open it in xaml editor, i can annotate specified line, but i cant select the block, which i need"